# Laravel unit test scandir fails because base path is wrong

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a controller that gets list of images from folders and passes them to the view:

```
public function create()
{
    $marker_images = scandir("./img/markers");
    $background_images = scandir("./img/backgrounds");
    $type = new Type();
    return view('admin.types.create',compact('type','marker_images','background_images'));
}
```

This works fine until i run my unit test, which then fails on the scandir step with

```
failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

if I add

```
exec('pwd',$return);
    print_r($return);
```

I see that the path is changing, when i manually vist the page the path is

```
/Users/<my username>/Sites/core-site/public
```

but when the unit test is executed

```
/Users/<my username>/Sites/core-site
```

how do I get it to pick the correct base path for the unit test?

my unit test looks like this:

```
public function testTypesCreate()
{

    $controller = $this->app->make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TypeController');
    $response = $controller->create();
    $this->assertEquals($response->name(), 'admin.types.create');

}
```

Comment: `./` will change with the executing file. Is using absolute paths a possibility?

Comment: No they aren't as the root path on my local machine is different from that of the production servers

Comment: Right, of course. How about using `__DIR__`? Or using environment variables to set the root path.

Comment: Ah perfect, I actually ended up using base_path(), but still you got me there Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.